# How to show Campaign History as VF relatedList component?

Tags: apex, related-list

Campaign Related list doesn't work. It gives me this error:

'Campaign History' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Lead

The code is below. Can anyone assist me?

Thanks,

Darko

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" showHeader="true" wizard="false" readOnly="false" rendered="true" showChat="true" standardStylesheets="true"
      tabStyle="Lead"  >
   <style>
      .activeTab {background-color: #236FBD; color:white; width: 170px; height: 20px; padding-top: 6px; font-size: 12px; font-style: bold; border-top: none;
         background-image:none;}
      .inactiveTab { background-color: lightgrey; color:black; width: 170px; height: 20px; padding-top: 6px; font-size: 12px; font-style: bold; border: none;
         background-image: none}
   </style>

<apex:pageBlock id="block1">
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="section2" columns="2" collapsible="true" title="Important Information!" >




    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <script>
        twistSection(document.getElementById('{!$Component.block1.section1}').getElementsByTagName('img')[0])
    </script>

</apex:pageBlock>
   <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="tabdetails" 
                  id="LeadTabPanel" tabClass="activeTab" 
                  inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab"  >   
      <apex:tab label="Details" name="LeadDetails" id="tabdetails" style="background-color: white;">
         <apex:detail relatedList="false" title="true" inlineEdit="true"/>
      </apex:tab>
      <apex:tab label="CampaignHistory" name="childCampaigns" id="tabContact" >
         <apex:relatedList subject="{!Lead}" list="Campaign History"  />
      </apex:tab>
      <apex:tab label="Opportunities" name="Opportunities" 
                id="tabOpp">
         <apex:relatedList subject="{!Lead}" 
                           list="Opportunities" />
      </apex:tab>
      <apex:tab label="Open Activities" name="OpenActivities" 
                id="tabOpenAct">
         <apex:relatedList subject="{!Lead}" 
                           list="OpenActivities" />
      </apex:tab>
      <apex:tab label="Activity History" name="ActivityHistory" id="tabActHist">
          <apex:relatedList subject="{!Lead}" list="ActivityHistories" />
      </apex:tab>
      <apex:tab label="Notes & Attachments" 
                name="NotesAndAttachments" id="tabNoteAtt" >
         <apex:relatedList subject="{!Lead}" 
                           list="CombinedAttachments" />
      </apex:tab>
   </apex:tabPanel>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem. Instead of using Campaign History, I should use CampaignMembers.

```
<apex:tab label="Campaign History" name="CampaignMembers" id="tabContact" >
         <apex:relatedList subject="{!Lead}" list="CampaignMembers"  />
      </apex:tab>
```