# Visualforce customization isn't displaying multiple fields

Tags: apex, visualforce, leads, related-list

[image]I am using the following VF page for Lead related List VF page and it is not working

```
{
<apex:page standardController="Lead">
  <apex:relatedList list="Campaign History" />
  <apex:relatedList list="Opportunities" />
  <apex:relatedList list="Activity History" />
  <apex:relatedList list="Notes" />
  <apex:relatedList list="Open Activities" />
</apex:page>
                }
```

Comment: Can you define "not working"?  What do you see?

Comment: /apex/CustomLayout?id=00***********     'Campaign History' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Lead 
This is coming for all object related list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this issue is that the relatedList is not named "Campaign Histories"

Use:

```
<apex:relatedList list="CampaignMembers"/>
```

apex:relatedList `list=` values have to be valid relationship names taken from the schema. The friendly name as shown to the user is confusingly only tangentially related to the real relationship name.

[image]

Comment: Thanks :)  How to take opportunity in related list as it is not working

Comment: @cloudlover in your screen shot you do not have an Opportunity related list, also do not believe there to be one unless you created a custom relationship which then you would need to use the custom fields child relationship name.

Comment: @cloudlover - `Opportunities` would be the name of an OOB relationship from Lead to Opportunity. There is no such OOB relationship. If you have a custom relationship, it would most likely be named `Opportunities__r` but custom relationships between Lead and Opportunity are extremely rare as once the Lead is converted, it disappears from user view

Answer (score 3):

You have to use related list's reference names, not the titles. Here is 2 examples:

`<apex:page standardController="Lead">
   <apex:relatedList list="OpenActivities" />
   <apex:relatedList list="ActivityHistories" />
 </apex:page>`

Unfortunately I don't know the names for other, and it doesn't look like you could have all listed, but there are also `NotesAndAttachments`, `Histories`, and `CampaignMembers` as @cropredy is pointing out in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

The issue could be related to this one from the knowledge article [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004556&language=en_US):

> **Description**
>
> This error occurs on a VisualForce page when a related list is being
> referenced but isn't available on the user's page. An example of this
> error would be
>
> 'OpenActivities' is not a valid child relationship name for
> entityOpportunity.
>
> The problem can appear confusing when the related list is actually
> added to the page layout by the system administrator.
>
> **Resolution**
>
> However the related list has been removed by the individual user (it
> doesn't appear only for the user receiving the error message). The
> related list can be added back in by going to:
>
> Setup | My Personal Information | Change My Display | Customize My
> Pages | Select the (custom/standard object) from the list | Customize
> My Pages.
>
> Add the related list that is referenced at the start of the error
> message into the selected list and click save. This should resolve the
> error message.

Note: Some child relationship names are not the plural of the object name like the following:
HTML Email Status: "EmailStatuses", Activity History: "ActivityHistories", Notes and Attachments: "NotesAndAttachments", Approval History: "ProcessSteps", Campaign History: "CampaignMembers".

Comment: I have checked those things and they are already present

Comment: @cloudlover it looks like another user ran into this issue as well and ended up using CampaignMembers vs History. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68070/how-to-show-campaign-history-as-vf-relatedlist-component